# Is there a way to turn down my PS4 controller's speaker volume?

Tags: controllers, ps4

So in some games (Electronic Super Joy, God Eater 2), I've noticed that the game makes use of the controller's built-in speaker to say things to the player. It's a cool feature and I like having it on, but *it's just way too loud.* Is there a setting in-game (for any games) or on the system itself to change the volume of the controller's speaker output?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

1. Hold the Playstation Button
2. Select Adjust Devices
3. Lower the volume

<sub>[(Source)](http://www.pushsquare.com/news/2013/11/guide_how_to_change_the_ps4_controllers_volume)</sub>

Comment: Wow you'd have thought I would've figured this out on my own... Thanks, man!

Comment: It is also great if you are playing on a screen without built-in speaker, and have to use mobile speaker linked to the controller.

Answer (score 5):

You can set the controller speaker volume in the console's system settings:

*Settings > Devices > Controllers > Volume Control (Speaker for Controller)*

From there, you can adjust the volume, which will apply to all games.

**Edit**: Timmy Jim's answer provides a much quicker and simpler way of doing this.